# How to refresh jquery mobile multipage document after deploying new software

Tags: caching, jquery-mobile, browser-cache

I have a jqm multipage document (index.html) that includes several pages and other assets (js, css, etc.). I have my server configured to use etags for the html, css, and js files. The request/response headers are set appropriately and it works as expected.

During use of my application there are no requests (with the exception of signing off) to index.html, so there is never really a chance for the browser to see if there is a new file out there, let alone all of it's css and js files (unless the user signs off, requests the page again or does a refresh). If I deploy new software, how might I notify the user that new sw is available and/or somehow force a refresh of the index.html file?

My initial thoughts were to store the version # on the client and periodically make ajax requests to the server to check the version #. If new sw is available, display a link to notify the user informing them of the new sw and to click on the link to get it (reload index.html).

I'm curious how others have done this? Thoughts? Recommendations?

Comment: Why not use the appcache? That way if you update your js/css/html all you need to do is ammend the appcache

Answer (score -1):

> If you link to multipage document, you must use a data-ajax="false"
> attribute on the link to cause a full page refresh due to the
> limitation above where we only load the first page node in an Ajax
> request due to potential hash collisions. There is currently a subpage
> plugin that makes it possible to load in multi-page documents.

Reference: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html

Please also look at this:

> **Cases when Ajax navigation will not be used**
>
> Under certain conditions,
> normal http requests will be used instead of Ajax requests. One case
> where this is true is when linking to pages on external websites. You
> can also specify that a normal http request be made through the
> following link attributes:
>
> rel=external
>
> target (with any value, such as "_blank")

If the pages is loaded as http request instead of Ajax, the problem would be solved.

Comment: This is not a good option, it means we lose page transitions.